# Looping through end of data file

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

I've been working on a problem set for the Harvard CS50 class and we have been tasked with recovering jpegs from a memory card. The card stores the jpgs sequentially. In writing my program I decided on using a while loop to keep looping through until EOF, but using the debugger included with the course I am finding that my loop never initiates. I have included my code below and I am really hoping somebody can help me understand where I went wrong in my loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper Usage
    if (argc != 1)
    {
        printf("This file takes no input commands!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open up card data file
    FILE* dataFile = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (dataFile == NULL) 
    {
        char* invalidFile = "card.raw";
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", invalidFile);
        return 2;
    }

    // Create variable to keep track of num of output files written
    int numFiles = 0;

    // Create buffer
    int* buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 512);

    // Create new file conditions
    bool a = buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff;
    bool b = buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1|| buffer[3] == 0xe2 || 
             buffer[3] == 0xe3 || buffer[3] == 0xe4 || buffer[3] == 0xe5 || 
             buffer[3] == 0xe6 || buffer[3] == 0xe7 || buffer[3] == 0xe8 || 
             buffer[3] == 0xe9 || buffer[3] == 0xea || buffer[3] == 0xeb || 
             buffer[3] == 0xec || buffer[3] == 0xed || buffer[3] == 0xee || 
             buffer[3] == 0xef;

    // Loop through until all files found         
    while(fread(&buffer, 512, 1, dataFile) == 1)
    {
        if(a && b)
        {
            // Create temporary storage
            char title[999];
            // print new file name
            sprintf(title, "%d.jpg", numFiles);
            // open new file
            FILE* img = fopen(&title[numFiles], "a");
            numFiles = numFiles + 1;
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
            free(buffer);
        }
        else 
        {
            if(numFiles > 0) 
            {

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you read the man page of `fread` you will notice that it's return value is the number of bytes that have been read. Sooo thats one of your problems.
Let me rephrase the other one as: Why do you assume that once you get the loop to start that `a` or `b` will have any other value than that which you assigned to them *before* the loop.

Comment: Clever you! C is not an interpreter, so `bool a = ...` is evaluated once and then used. But you want to have it evaluated every time. And you evaluate it on a buffer with random values! Go back and study your course material.

Comment: @Mathstudent what is the return value of "fread(&buffer, 512, 1, dataFile)" ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments! it was my understanding that fread would return 1 each time through the loop, which is the same as nmemb(3rd entry). My conditions for the file headers was something I just added, and I will change it back to the original way I had it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay you might have more than one misunderstanding.

First of all take a look at the *man page* of [**fread**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread):

> On success, **fread()** and **fwrite()** return the number of *items* read or written.

So if you request **512** bytes you should expect it to return **512**.
If it returns less, you know: Either you reached the end of your file or something went wrong.

Also if you assign:

```
bool a = something;
bool b = somethingElse;
```

And then:

```
while(somethingEntirelyElse) {
    // Never update the value of a or b
    if(a && b) { ... }
    // Neither here ...
}
```

Then you could call that check *redundant* couldn't you?

That is unless `a` and `b` actually are *volatile*. But **don't** go there!

In your case the assignment of `a` and `b` most likely belongs *inside* the `while` loop.

Then you *alloc* your `buffer` once outside the loop, but *free* it each time you actually write it down. On the next iteration you **will** get a *segmentation fault*.

Have you considered what happens if any of the image files is any other size than 512 bytes, and the images are not aligned properly?

A better way would be to save the position of the start of one file and once you encounter the EOF (which you aren't really looking for...) you would know the exact size of the file, and how big your buffer would have to be.

---

In conclusion I would agree with some of the commenters, that you really should have a look at some earlier assignments and see whether you can learn something from them.

---

Analogy time:

Let's assume you have a book, and you want to copy each page that has an image on it.
You tell yourself: Aw I just follow a simple algorithm, so I can think about something else.

**Your** algorithm is:

- Have a photocopy machine
- Have a notebook on which you note whether a page contains an image or not.
- Take a look at the (as of yet closed book) and see if there is an image. -> Write down result on notebook
- Start turning the pages as long as the *next* page has exactly one letter on it. (No more no less) -> you stop immediately in most cases
- If the notebook says: There is an image, copy this page (note that the notebook will say whatever you wrote on it the first time)
- If you just copied an image, throw away your copying machine (and don't bother buying a new one for the next image)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very clear. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `malloc`, the `buffer` points to allocated memory (hopefully; you should check that `buffer != null`), but the contents of that memory is undefined. Nevertheless, you use it and compare it to `0xFF`, which is meaningless. You first have to read data from the file.

Files are usually made up from bytes, not ints, so your buffer should be of type `unsigned char *`.